# collision detection and creation in xcode class

Tags: ios, xcode, class, collision-detection

I'm working on making a new app in xcode and have run into two problems that always seem to be a problem when I program large projects.
Basically, I want the user of this app to be able to input specifics like size, position, color, and possibly speed and/or direction.
These inputs will create a square of specific size, position, and color which will move around the screen and interact with other squares the user has created.
Now here are my problems:
First: I have absolutely no idea how to create something in code. I know I almost certainly have to do this in a class, but I've never figured out how to do this in a single programming language.
Second: Interaction between the squares.  How do I detect collisions between the possibly dozens or hundreds of squares the user creates.

I'd really like to figure out how to do this, especially because I'm sure it'll be helpful in not only this, but many other future projects.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using sprite kit for the collision detection and creation of the squares. You'll probably want to subclass SKSpriteNode to define the properties for your squares.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html